# "Рейтинг" слов в индексе Sphinx

Tags: sphinx

Настроил Sphinx. Проиндексировал source. Решил оптимизировать список стоп-слов, а заодно посмотреть часто употребляемые слова в базе - т.е. вывести слова в моем индексе Sphinx в порядке убывания "встречаемости".

Нужно получить, что-то вроде списка "слово_в_приведенной_форме": количество_вхождений. Пример:

```
и: 1394783948
в: 3482575
дом: 23415
участок: 1241
синхрофазатрон: 1
```

Как это сделать?

Comment: Есть подозрение, что это невозможно, потому что вряд ли индекс хранит исходные слова. Можно разбить текст на токены с помощью [CALL KEYWORDS](http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/current/sphinxql-call-keywords.html) и потом вручную/скриптом посчитать, но это опять нужно скармливать все тексты

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Есть специальный режим индексации для этого - `indexer --buildstops ... --buildfreqs`. На уже построенном индексе в общем случае такое сделать невозможно, т.к. начальные формы могут быть потеряны при нормализации токенов (морфология, exceptions и пр).

Comment: спасибо. То что надо! Я как раз имел ввиду слова в "нормализованном виде"